# phpbb behind a reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, reverse-proxy, phpbb

i've got a django app running on apache behind an nginx reverse proxy. Nginx takes requests on port 80 and forwards them to apache on 127.0.0.1:81. This works fine.

Now I want to run phpbb on apache under /forums. My problem is that when phpbb does a redirect, it seems to redirect to the internal apache port, rather than port 80. So, for instance when I first go to http:*//my-dev-server/forums to configure php bb, it immediately redirects to http:*//127.0.0.1:81/forums/install/index.php.

Is there something I need to do in nginx/apache/phpbb config to get it to redirect to the external port? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not used phpbb myself, but according to the [function generate_board_urls()](https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb3/blob/5ec1c887959be5629c8a4c712b152d58058929a8/phpBB/includes/functions.php#L2253) there's a config value called "force_server_vars".  When this is set you must also configure "server_protocol" (eg "http"), "server_name" ("my-dev-server"), "server_port" ("80") and "server_path" (I presume "/forums" or some variation)

Comment: Good grief, I'm not sure how this didn't occur to me. Thanks very much.